# React/Zustand - Module parse failed: Unexpected token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zustand

I am facing an error in my react app, not sure where the error itself is coming from and the code seems to be clean and bug-free and also following best practices.

`Error Log`

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/CourseList.jsx 74:14
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (74:14)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         columnNumber: 17
|       }
>     }, course?.title), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("button", {
|       className: "delete-btn",
|       onClick: function onClick() {
```

`courseList.jsx`

```
<span className="course-title">{course?.title}</span>
  <button
    className="delete-btn"
    onClick={() => {
      removeCourse(course.id);
    }}
  >
    Delete Course
  </button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a really long time debugging what the issue was and so many tries, I later got what the issue was but don't understand why that itself was what was throwing the issue.

I simply had to change this, `{course?.title}` to this `{course.title}` and the code got compiled successfully without issues. Thereby, removing the `?` to make it work.

I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: You have something misconfigured in webpack or babel